# How to select all tabs to the right of current tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

If you right click on any tab at the top of Chrome browser, you will see an option called ***Close tabs to the right***. This closes all tabs to the right of the current active tab. I'm trying to do something similar with a Chrome extension. Can the tabs to the right be selected using a loop like "for index of current active tab until index of last tab?"

Following is the source code of an open source Chrome extension. The function selects all tabs in the current window except for the active tab and "suspends" them. I am trying to write a similar function but instead of all tabs, it needs to select only the tabs to the right of the active tab.

```
  function suspendAllTabs(force) {
    const forceLevel = force ? 1 : 2;
    getCurrentlyActiveTab(activeTab => {
      if (!activeTab) {
        gsUtils.warning(
          'background',
          'Could not determine currently active window.'
        );
        return;
      }
      chrome.windows.get(activeTab.windowId, { populate: true }, curWindow => {
        for (const tab of curWindow.tabs) {
          if (!tab.active) {
            gsTabSuspendManager.queueTabForSuspension(tab, forceLevel);
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each tab has an `index` which shows its position. For example, the 3rd tab will have an index of 2 (starts from 0).

Therefore, tab to the right of the any tab means `tab.index +1` to `tabs.length`

For example ...
**Getting the tabs to the right of the active tab**

```
// get all the tabs in current window
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, tabs => {

  let activeIndex;
  for (const tab of tabs) {
    // set the activeIndex so we wont have to run a loop on the tabs twice
    if (tab.active) { activeIndex = tab.index; }

    // tabs to the right of the active tab will have higher index
    if(typeof activeIndex !== 'undefined' && tab.index > activeIndex) {

      // tabs is on the right of the active tab ... do whatever needed
    }
  }
});
```

**Getting the tabs to the left of the active tab**

```
// get all the tabs in current window
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, tabs => {

  for (const tab of tabs) {
    // stop when reached the active tab
    if (tab.active) { break; }

    // tabs to the left of the active tab ... do whatever needed
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I was able to implement it, both left and right. For left, I had to run the loop twice.

Comment: @NoobCoder No need to run the loop twice.. in fact tabs to the left is simpler. I updated the answer to include tabs to the left.

Comment: @erosman is there a reason why simple filtering wouldn’t work? You have your array of tab objects, so filter to get the ones you need based on comparison with current tab index. Seems much more intuitive and simpler to implement.

Comment: @lbragile That works too. The difference is if you have to do something with each of those tabs, the filter would require to loop through to create another filtered array and then run whatever function on the array, so that means looping twice. This way you only loop once.

Comment: @erosman makes sense. In my case it makes more sense to do filtering but I see where your approach is useful as well. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Another option which can be useful in many situations and is very intuitive is to use filtering to get your new tabs.

Adding to @erosman’s answer. When you get the tabs you can:

```
// All to right of current
tabs = tabs.filter((x)=> x.index > activeTab.index);

// All to left of current 
tabs = tabs.filter((x)=> x.index < activeTab.index);

// Do whatever with the new tabs.
```

Similar approach can be taken to get any tab as long as the condition in the filter is met!